# Jquery events from dynamically generated controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, client-side

I have a button controls with ids generated by  pattern as search results 
this is object id.

in first search i Have 3 results:

```
<input type="button" id="product_0" > 
<input type="button" id="product_1" >
<input type="button" id="product_2" >
```

Another result builds me 2 results

```
<input type="button" id="product_23" >
<input type="button" id="product_34" >
```

how can I handle their events in jquery?

for example:

```
$("product_id").click(function(){

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that `live` is deprecated, updated the answer:

If there is a much closer parent that is not dynamically added, use that instead of document as parent selector

```
$(document).on("click", [id^=product_]", function(){  
 //Your Code to handle the click.
});
```

<del>Use jquery live function.
e.g:

    $("[id^=product_]").live("click", function(){  
     //Your Code to handle the click.
    });</del>

Comment: Cybernate has a much better selector, so you should go with his response.

Comment: out of date but coming up as first results in Google.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("product_id").live("click", function(){

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: if i'm not confusing anything then selecting "product_id" won't.

Comment: out of date but coming up as first results in Google.